# TeraData query in VBA with volatile table

Tags: sql, vba, teradata, volatile, recordset

I'm trying to automate a sequence of queries. One query, say Q1, is problematic as it creates a volatile table prior to the select statement. Within TeraData, Q1 runs fine but when passing Q1 to TeraData through VBA I get an error:

> Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.

Q1 is of the form:

```
    create multiset volatile table volatileTable,
    no fallback,
    no before journal,
    no after journal,
    (
        a1,
        a2,
        a3,
        a4,
        a5
    ) as 
    (sel
        b1,
        b2,
        b3,
        min(b4) as a1,
        min(b5) as a2
    from
        db.table
    where
        b6 = 'condition'
    group by
        b1,
        b2,
        b3
    )
    with data
    on commit preserve rows;

    sel
        c1,
        c2,
        c3
    from 
        db.table
    group by
        1,
        2

    union

    sel
        d1,
        d2,
        d3
    from 
        (sel
            e.f1,
            e.f2,
            e.f3,
            e.a1,
            s.a1,
            e.a2,
            s.a2,
            e.a3,
            s.a3,
            e.a4,
            s.a4,
            e.a5,
            s.a5
        from 
            db.table) as e
            left outer join volatileTable as s
            on
                e.a1 = s.a1
                e.a2 = s.a2
                e.a3 = s.a3
                e.a4 >= s.a4
                e.a5 <= s.a5    
    group by
        1,
        2

    union

    sel
        g1,
        g2,
        g3
    from 
        db.table
    group by
        1,
        2

    union

    ...
```

The problem has got to be with creating a volatile table within the VBA `ADODB.Command.Execute()` statement. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You are connectected in BT/ET mode. After executing the Q1 query, execute "ET" command to end the transaction.

Or you could connect in Teradata default mode to do auto commit of queries.

Comment: I've tried wrapping Q1 in BT and ET. I've also tried wrapping just the create volatile statement in BT and ET. Both give me the same error described in the original post.

Comment: How do I choose what mode I connect to Teradata in through VBA? My current VBA connection reads `connection.Open "Data Source = environment; Database = db; Persist Security Info = True; User ID= UID; Password= PW; Session Mode=ANSI;"`

Comment: Right, I thought so. But then the question still stands: Why am I getting the no-DML-after-DDL error?

Answer (score 0):

You must send the Create and the Select in two separate requests.

In an ANSI session you  must add a **COMMIT;** to the Create after *on commit preserve rows;*

To switch to from an ANSI to a Teradata session you need to change to **Session Mode=Teradata;**

If you're in a Teradata mode session, there's no need for BT/ET as every request is an implicit transaction.

Comment: How do I send two separate requests within one Teradata session? Right now, I have a single execute line reading `recordSet = cmdSQL.Execute()`. Forgive me, I'm just learning how to get at Teradata through VBA.

Comment: In the above comment: `cmdSQL.CommandText = queryFromFile` with `queryFromFile` as a string and `cmdSQL.commandType = adCmdText`.

Comment: You'll have to have two separate execute requests, one for the `create as...`, one for the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the connection parameters to:

   connection.Open "Data Source = environment; Database = db; Persist Security Info = True; User ID= UID; Password= PW; Session Mode=Teradata;"
2. Break the Create Volatile Table and Select from the volatile table into two separate queries/ Command Text. You also need two different recordsets (adoDbRs1,adoDbRs2 in my case).

a. CREATE Query (No `COMMITT;` needed after `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;`) :

```
selectCmd.CommandText = SqlQuery1 'SqlQuery has the Create Volatile Table (A) Query'
Set adoDbRs1 = selectCmd.Execute(, , adCmdText)
```

b. SELECT Query:

```
SqlQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM A"
selectCmd.CommandText = SqlQuery2
Set adoDbRs2 = selectCmd.Execute(, , adCmdText)
```

c. Paste the record set:

```
Worksheets("Mysheet").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset adoDbRs2
```